# oracle empty object returned

Tags: javascript, database, oracle

I'm have a problem with some testing I'm doing on a local Oracle DB. Below is my JS code. Essentially if I 'Alert' or 'Write' the returned data from the DB I get what I expected back. But I can't find a way to put the data in an array, or assign it to a variable. When I console log it out it looks like an empty object? - Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help much appreciated.

```
//Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 64 bit Production ;

var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var connectionstring=" My string is here...";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

sql="SELECT Tail_number FROM aircraft"
rs.Open(sql, connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
var testthis = rs.fields(0);  //This does not work,
console.log(testthis); // Neither does this, just returns an empty object

document.write(rs.fields(0)); //This will successfully send the output to the 
screen
document.write("<br>");
rs.movenext;
}
rs.close;
connection.close;

</script>
```

[This is what I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONmLG.png)

Comment: Is the `fields` object supposed to be an array? Arrays are indexed using square braces in Javascript not `()`. What you are doing is calling a function called `fields` with parameter value 0.

Comment: Its odd, it looks like an array, but with nothing inside. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONmLG.png - here is a picture of what I see in the console

Comment: From your picture (if its of the fields object, its not clear), fields looks to be an array of objects which means you need to refer to it using `fields[0]` and not `fields(0)`

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm not back in work until next week now, but I will give that a go then and let you know how I get on. regards  Peter